# Select2 exibe valor em vez do texto

Tags: json, twig, silex, jquery-select2

Tenho alguns campos que utilizam Select2 para fazer um CRUD básico, mas consultando alguns campos de outra base. A questão é, quando clico em atualizar, coloco num array todos os valores da tabela (dataTables) e depois quando passo para o Select2, ele não exibe o texto correspondente e sim, o valor que recebeu. Seguem os códigos:

```
$('#grid_tbl tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
var select =  $('#grid_tbl').DataTable().row(this).data();
$('#equipamento').select2("val", select.equipamento);
});

$('#equipamento').select2({
    placeholder: "Digite o Equipamento",
    initSelection: function(element, callback){
        callback({id: element.val(), text:element.val()})
    },
   quietMillis: 100,
   ajax: {
      url: "json/finalidade",
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: function (term, page) {
        return {
                term: term, //search term
                page_limit: 10 // page size
               };
        },
  results: function (data, page) {
  return { results: data };
   }
  }

 });

$formJson->post('/finalidade', function(Request $request) use($app) {
$post = $request->request->all();
$term = $post["term"];
$sql = "SELECT
TRIM(cdfin) cdfin
,TRIM(dsfin) dsfin
FROM
gmt_pend_mnfinali
WHERE
cdfin||dsfin ILIKE '%{$term}%'
ORDER BY
cdfin ASC LIMIT 60";
$result = $app['db']->fetchAll($sql);   
        if (count($result) == 0) {
        return $app->json(array(), 201);
}   
        foreach ($result as &$v) {
        $v['id'] = utf8_encode($v['cdfin']);
                $v['text'] = utf8_encode($v['cdfin'].' - '.$v['dsfin']) ;
}

        return $app->json($result, 201);
});
```

Comment: Como está o código do seu arquivo de busca ?

Comment: Acrescentei o código à pergunta

Comment: Se no `return` você colocar: `console.log(data)` o que aparece no Console Inspect Element do Chrome ?

Comment: Imagino que esteja dizendo no `return` do select2, ele retorna o json. Na verdade, não retorna nada se eu não clicar no campo. Ele vem preenchido, mas com o valor.

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?

Comment: Cara, desculpa, fui transferido na empresa umas 5 vezes, abandonei o projeto e por fim me pediram para retomar com outro escopo.Quando chegar nessa parte de novo eu relembro e respondo